# Write to USB flash drive extremely slow

Tags: usb, usb-drive

When I'm copying a copying a large file to a 8GB pendrive, the write crawls at some 10's of kB/s. Even after killing the process with Ctrl+C, the writing continues for several minutes. (the task manager applet and the "bo" field of `vmstat`)

This happens intermittently and sometimes can be fixed by remounting the drive.

1. What could be causing this? (I think it's something in the kernel, because killing the process doest
2. How could I debug/find out what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a 8GB flash drive and it turned out to be poor contact of the USB port on the stick. So I suggest before starting to mess around with the kernel you check to see if the contacts are clean. Also some times (on really cheap sticks) the plug contact is made of sub-standard material and tends to wear out causing slow transmission speeds. (I had the same problem with very cheap external hdd cables)

Comment: reeeally?! 8o wow. ok. that kind of makes sense. I'll try that. thanks. (the contact was bad.. it kept getting disconnected if I shook the machine)

Comment: This is a long standing issue and the answer has been that this issue is caused by crappy hardware (the USB sticks, even from well recognized manufacturers). However since Sarah made [this](https://plus.google.com/u/0/116960357493251979546/posts/RZpndv4BCCD) rather unrelated post, stating that they blamed manufacturers for crappy hardware while ignoring that they really had a bug in the kernel, I am no longer willing to accept this answer. Nope, this is nothing against Sarah or any other maintiner. Please give your best shot at filing a bug, or don't use USB sticks when you rely on speed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with expensive hardware as well (Seagate HDD 2.5, Kingston DT Flash). Cheap ones woks even better. Don't matter if this is USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 port. Speed is always about 10 MB/s during write to disk. Read from disk and access is fast. This problem is only in Ubuntu. Windows and openSUSE works fine. Kernel doesn't matter too. The newest Ubuntu beta 13.10 with newest kernel have the same problem. I noticed better speed at Ubuntu LTS version (kernel version don't matter). Laptop has worse speed than PC.

Looks like Ubuntu don't care about it. Most of all issues are unassigned, expired, not solved... too bad. People go to Windows...